# I got an email saying "Are you still actively looking for a job?" I click "Actively Looking", and it takes me to "Page Not Found"

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I got an email from Stack Overflow, looking like this:

[image: Email from Stack Overflow]

I press "I'm still actively looking", and it takes me to a page looking like this:

[image: Stack Overflow Talent - Page Not Found]

The URL was something like (I removed the parts for privacy sakes):

```
http://talent.stackoverflow.com/email-cta/set-active/<six numbers>?token=<5 letters / numbers>&cw=1
```

Just listing this here so that this can be fixed.

Comment: Just curious to know what could have been tracked if the part of the URL was not removed?

Comment: @ManojKumar a minimal set of data: your account, your email, where you live, martial status, when you were born, your daily commute route, last holiday destination, SSN, passport number, mobile phone number, savings account, how much you earn, your current employer, your address, which devices you own, what food you like, favorite holiday destination, your religion, your political color, your shoe-size, color of your eyes, how tall you are, your weight, if you ever parsed html with regex and if you use tabs or spaces.

Comment: @rene You forgot "If you've ever used jQuery or not."

Comment: @rene: would be nice if the page would **redirect to an online form of the users country to file for unemployment benefit and filling that form with all that personal data**. After all, we have a *be nice* policy. Showing somebody looking for a job the "Page Not Found" page is like telling them "there's no hope for you". That redirection would be a lot more constructive. ;-)

Comment: @rene: When the war begins, you're going to be so glad they tracked martial status and know exactly who all the black belts are.

Comment: That happened to me a few days ago, but I closed the tab and clicked the link again and it worked.

Comment: "Stack Overflow talent not found"

Comment: @rene It's reassuring to know that I know my security when it comes to sanitizing URLs in Stack Exchange questions. Good list - I have never parsed HTML with regex, and I use tabs, not spaces fyi :)

Comment: @rene that's some pretty sensitive data. I mean, I have nothing to hide, but the answer to "[have] you ever parsed html with regex" brings back painful memories of the time before I was a good programmer that I don't want to be out in the open

Comment: [Are you still actively looking for this web page?](http://stackoverflow.com/404)

Comment: Thanks, reproed, looking into the fix now.

Comment: @ManojKumar those are simply your account id and a token which identifies you, so that someone else cannot execute an action (marking your job search status as active) on your behalf if they know your account id.

Comment: @think123 Think again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is now fixed. It affected a subset of users and was related to the recent launch of [Talent](https://business.stackoverflow.com/talent).

Thanks for the report!